# Making a network structure json

Tags: java, json, d3.js

I am new in D3. While I was working on it, I came by a requirement where I have to build a json like this-

```
 {
  "nodes":[
      {"name":"0","group":1},
      {"name":"1","group":1},
      {"name":"2","group":10},
      {"name":"3","group":1},
      {"name":"4","group":1}    
 ],
  "links":[
      {"source":1,"target":0},
      {"source":2,"target":0},
      {"source":3,"target":0},
      {"source":3,"target":2},
      {"source":2,"target":4},
      {"source":1,"target":4}
 ]
}
```

What I made is like this-

```
"allCalls":[{"Name":"Voice","Data":"40"},
        {"Name":"SMS","Data":"30"},
        {"Name":"MMS","Data":"5"},
        {"Name":"GPRS","Data":"20"},
        {"Name":"Others","Data":"5"}],
   "allCallsRatio":5}
```

Here is the servlet

```
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String start = request.getParameter("source");
    String end = request.getParameter("count");

    if (start == null && end == null) {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        ArrayList<IndCallType> ratios = new ArrayList<IndCallType>();
        ratios.add(new IndCallType("Voice", "40"));
        ratios.add(new IndCallType("SMS", "30"));
        ratios.add(new IndCallType("MMS", "5"));
        ratios.add(new IndCallType("GPRS", "20"));
        ratios.add(new IndCallType("Others", "5"));
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        JsonArray arrayObj = new JsonArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < ratios.size(); i++) {
            IndCallType count = ratios.get(i);
            JsonElement linObj = gson.toJsonTree(count);
            arrayObj.add(linObj);
        }

        JsonObject myObj = new JsonObject();
        myObj.addProperty("success", true);
        myObj.add("allCalls", arrayObj);
        myObj.addProperty("allCallsRatio", ratios.size());

        System.out.println(myObj.toString());
```

I gave the main part of the servlet where I buid the JSON.
But its not what I want... Can any one help me...

Comment: Where's the Java code, and how does it interact with d3.js? Is your server-side code in Java?

Comment: I gave the main of the servlet where i create json

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Is it that you don't want "Name" and instead  want "name". Or you want "group" instead of "Data"?

Comment: Actually What I made is 1 group i.e. "allCalls" But I need 2 groups links and nodes both in one json

Answer (score 0):

I understood that you need something to serialize the *first* JSON you posted. The most simple way is to build corresponding POJOs and then serialize them using Gson. You can forget all the Json*.java stuff. Gson will do all work for you.

Here's an example you can directly copy and run into you IDE that shows the idea. You can easily adapt it to your code.

```
package stackoverflow.questions;

import java.util.*;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class Q20162819 {

   public static class Node {
      String name;
      Integer group;

      public Node(String name, Integer group) {
         this.name = name;
         this.group = group;
      }

   }

   public static class Link {
      Integer source;
      Integer target;

      public Link(Integer source, Integer target) {
         this.source = source;
         this.target = target;
      }
   }

   public static class Data {
      List<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<>(); // java7
      List<Link> links = new ArrayList<>(); // java7
   }

   /**
    * @param args
    */
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Data d = new Data();
      d.links.add(new Link(0, 1));
      d.links.add(new Link(2, 10));
      d.links.add(new Link(1, 20));

      d.nodes.add(new Node("1", 1));
      d.nodes.add(new Node("1", 2));
      d.nodes.add(new Node("3", 5));

      Gson g = new Gson();

      System.out.println(g.toJson(d));

   }

}
```

this is the result (I formatted it using [external tool](http://www.bodurov.com/JsonFormatter/view.aspx?json=%2520%2520%257B%2522nodes%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522name%2522%253A%25221%2522%252C%2522group%2522%253A1%257D%252C%257B%2522name%2522%253A%25221%2522%252C%2522group%2522%253A2%257D%252C%257B%2522name%2522%253A%25223%2522%252C%2522group%2522%253A5%257D%255D%252C%2522links%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522source%2522%253A0%252C%2522target%2522%253A1%257D%252C%257B%2522source%2522%253A2%252C%2522target%2522%253A10%257D%252C%257B%2522source%2522%253A1%252C%2522target%2522%253A20%257D%255D%257D%250A)).

```
{
    "nodes": [
        {
            "name": "1", 
            "group": 1
        }, 
        {
            "name": "1", 
            "group": 2
        }, 
        {
            "name": "3", 
            "group": 5
        }
    ], 
    "links": [
        {
            "source": 0, 
            "target": 1
        }, 
        {
            "source": 2, 
            "target": 10
        }, 
        {
            "source": 1, 
            "target": 20
        }
    ]
}
```